# iframe won't load correct hash in firefox

Tags: firefox, iframe, pushstate, postmessage, window.location

I have an iframe with a differing domain, I have no trouble resizing the iframe by communicating with the parent or the child using jQuery postMessage plugin. However, I have a single page app that scrolls through some steps and then loads in a results page via ajax. On this results page there are product links that need to load in the parent window. This works fine too. My problem is when the user clicks the back button, I want to regenerate and show the results, not the initial state of the page. On Chrome, this works fine but on Firefox it doesn't (when it's in an iframe, otherwise the url directly worked). It seems that Firefox ignores the hashes, cookies, pushState, etc that I've set. I'm not sure how to fix this, and any help would be appreciated.

First, I wanted to see if history api was available, when I call app.getResults() I check if it's available, otherwise set location.hash = "results". app.resultPageSetup(currentState) loads nicely the way I'd prefer because it skips the ajax call used to get the object, since I already saved it in the state.

```
var isHistory = function() {
 return !!(window.history && history.pushState);
};
//This "if" is for a different part of the app. Just ignore.
if ($('.not_container2').length) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    app.setFrameHeight("2500");
  }, 1000);
} else {
  if ( isHistory() === true  ) {
    var currentState = history.state;
    history.pushState('', '', '#steps');
    if (currentState !== null ) {
      $('.container').hide();
      $('.container2').show();
      app.resultPageSetup(currentState);
      app.resultPageComplete();
    } else {
      $('.container').show();
      $('.container2').hide();
      setTimeout(function() {
        if ($('.container').length){
          app.setFrameHeight("610");
        } else if ($('.not_container2').length) {
          app.setFrameHeight("2500");
        }
      }, 1000);
    }
  } else {
    //Firefox ignores this stuff. Chrome works. Doing without a cookie at all would be nice
    if (location.hash === "#results" && $.cookie("results") === "true") {
      $('.container').hide();
      $('.container2').show();
      app.getResults();
  } else if (location.hash === "") {
    $('.container').show();
    $('.container2').hide();
    $.cookie("results", null);
    setTimeout(function() {
      if ($('.container').length){
      app.setFrameHeight("610");
      } else if ($('.not_container2').length) {
        app.setFrameHeight("2500");
      }
    }, 1000);
  }
 }
}
```

Here are the links: The parent is http://www.hhgregg.com/productfinder/tv (choose the first option) and the iframe source is http://hhgregg-finders.gst.api.igodigital.com

I could also leverage $.postMessage by setting hashes on the parent, but I had trouble with this as well. Here is the general idea there:

```
$(function() {

  var iframe = $('#baseFrame');
  var h;
  var saved_state = "igo_steps";

  $.receiveMessage(function(e){
   var data = e.data.split("|");
   var height = data[0];
   var state = data[1];

   if (!isNaN(height)) {
    h = height;
   } else {
    h = "610";
   }
   iframe.attr("height", h);

   if (saved_state !== state) {
    window.location.hash = state;
    $.postMessage(window.location.hash, '*', document.getElementById("baseFrame").contentWindow);
   }
 }, 'http://hhgregg-finders.gst.api.igodigital.com');
});
```